# Script function not found when running time-driven triggers

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers

I'm getting the error below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg2GE.png)

Here is my script:

```
function getCoinData() {
  var queryString = Math.random();

  var getCoin = "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span";
  var Dolar = '=IMPORTXML("' + 'https://br.investing.com/currencies/usd-brl' + '?' + queryString + '";"'+ getCoin + '")';
  var Euro = '=IMPORTXML("' + 'https://br.investing.com/currencies/eur-brl' + '?' + queryString + '";"'+ getCoin + '")';
  var Bitcoin = '=IMPORTXML("' + 'https://br.investing.com/indices/investing.com-btc-brl' + '?' + queryString + '";"'+ getCoin + '")';
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D2').setValue(Dolar);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D3').setValue(Euro);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D4').setValue(Bitcoin);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you have a space in the name

Comment: Error messages should be added as text  not as image, also there are missing details. Please describe how the time-drive triggers were created and show the data shown  in the triggers page of the corresponding Apps Script project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! The code I used was:

```
function GetCoinTriggers() {
ScriptApp.newTrigger('getCoinData')
  .timeBased()
  .everyHours(4)
  .create();
}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).